# Unexpected output printing a float cast as an int

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a = 12.5;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)&a);

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, how do you interpret the expression `*(int *)&a`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It takes the address of a float, casts it to an integer pointer and then dereferences that as an integer. Totally wrong.

There are at least two things wrong here:

- Nobody says the pointers for an int and a float need to be the same size
- The representation for a float looks nothing like the representation for a signed int

So the output to the second printf (if it doesn't happen to crash since it's undefined behavior, as per the first point) would likely be some strange, huge number.

Comment: By the way, interesting thing here: http://codepad.org/n76EVlM1 ; Any ideas why printf("%d",a) always prints 0 and not same value as would interpreting float as int do? Trying to find an answer in printf man, but no idea yet.

Comment: @Михаил: Are you on x86_64? If so that would explain it.

Comment: @Михаил Страшун It uses a different representation. **It doesn't cast `a` to an integer**, it simply interprets the bits as "these meaningless bits are a signed integer".

Comment: The bit are not meaningless if you assume (as basically all real-world systems are) 32-bit twos-complement `int` and IEEE single-precision `float`.

Comment: @R: Can you elaborate on why printf("%d",a) prints 0.I got this output on gcc.

Comment: On x86_64, `a` is passed in a floating point (sse) register and `"%d"` is passed in the first general purpose register (rdi). The second general purpose register (rsi) is uninitialized so it merely contains whatever value it happened to have in the calling code.

Answer (score 3):

The author of this code is trying to take the bits of a float and reinterpret them as an int, but `*(int *)&a` invokes undefined behavior and modern compilers likely will not do what the author of the code intended. Passing an argument of the wrong type to `printf` is even worse undefined behavior; it definitely **will not work** on modern archs like x86_64. Instead you could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float a = 12.5;
  int b;
  memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b);
  printf("%d\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

My compiler flags this and issues a stern warning.

```
$ make foolish
cc     foolish.c   -o foolish
foolish.c: In function ‘main’:
foolish.c:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
$ ./foolish
1606416928
1095237632
$
```

What is the reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: to make mistakes and learn.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you make that line `printf("%08X\n", *(unsigned int *)&a);` then it prints the binary representation of the floating point number. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision) for details.

Comment: No, it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @R.: Hm, I guess it'd be safer to cast to `unsigned char *` (which you're allowed to do) and then print `sizeof(float)` units.

Comment: Yes, or use `memcpy` like I did to make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

The size of size(float) and sizeof(double) tend to be some multiple of at least sizeof(short), and often sizeof(int) (to meet different needs even the IEEE floating point standards allow multiple floating point formats).

Assuming the previously mentioned undefined pointer behaviors do not kill the program, in most environments this will just take the bits of one of those ints and print it out in isolation. The internals of floats assure that this will be vastly different from the original floating point value.

```
printf( "%d sizeof(short)\n", int(sizeof(short)) );
printf( "%d sizeof(int)\n", int(sizeof(int)) );
printf( "%d sizeof(float)\n", int(sizeof(float)) );
printf( "%d sizeof(double)\n", int(sizeof(double)) );
printf( "%d sizeof(long double)\n", int(sizeof(long double)) );
```